# Does $S=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k\exp ikx}{a^2-k^2}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I concluded that $S$ converges ($x\in\mathbb R$, $a\notin\mathbb Z$):
$$S=\displaystyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^k\exp ikx}{a^2-k^2}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k \cos kx}{a^2-k^2}+i\displaystyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^k \sin kx}{a^2-k^2}.$$
Under the given conditions, $(-1)^k \cos kx\le 1$ and $(-1)^k \sin kx\le 1$, so if $\sum_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{a^2-k^2}$ converges (which is true), then $S$ converges.

This result is contrary to Wolfram Alpha (it says the sum does not converge): 
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+(-1)%5Ek+exp(ikx)%2F(a%5E2-k%5E2)+from+-inf+to+inf

The purported error perhaps shouldn't be the matter of $a$ not being in $\mathbb Z$:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F(a%5E2-k%5E2)+from+-inf+to+inf

I don't know if I am missing something or if it's Alpha's error.

Comment: Yeah, the absolute values of the terms in the sum behave asymptotically as $|1/k^2|$, so the infinite sum should converge. I'm assuming WolframAlpha is getting confused by the divergence at integer values of $a$.

Comment: I thought so too but then it turned out that another series, also diverging at integer values of $a$, does not produce that "error": https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F(a%5E2-k%5E2)+from+-inf+to+inf

Comment: Then possibly Wolfram is allowing complex values for $x$?

Comment: Oh, that could be the reason.